# Windows 10 licence integrity on hard drive swap

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I need to replace a user's laptop to a new one.
The guy had to install a shit ton of customers' apps on it and I'd rather not reconfiguring a full windows instance and reinstalling each app.

So I thought about swapping his current hard drive to the new laptop directly.
My concern though is about the windows licence on the new computer.

If I'm not wrong, windows 10 licences are tied to the BIOS but how will the swap be handled by the laptop ?
Will it keep running flawlessly with the built-in licence or will there be some kind of conflict ?
The windows 10 version on each computer are the same (pro).

EDIT : Absolutely nothing in common with the proposed possible duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

After taking the leap, I can tell, if the windows 10 versions are the same, the swap will work flawlessly !